# url changes but blank page appears when using react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a navigation bar in my homepage and i need to redirect to the booking page when the user clicks on Reservations but it's not working. I see the url changes to ../booking but it only displays a blank page.
Here are my App.js, index.js and Nav.js codes:
I would really appreciate the help since I've been stuck on this for a few days now

```
import './App.css'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import Nav from './components/Nav'
import HomePage from './pages/Home/HomePage';
import BookingPage from './pages/Booking/BookingPage'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'


function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route exact path="/booking" element={<BookingPage />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App
```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

```
import React from 'react'
import navLogo from "../assets/nav-logo.svg"
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect } from 'react';



function Nav() {
  return (
    <body>
      <header>
      <img src={navLogo} alt="Little Lemon Logo" className='logo'/>
      <div  class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-icon"></div>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
        <li><Link className="a" to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link className="a" to="/">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link className="a" to="/">Menu</Link></li>
        <li><Link  to="/booking" className="a">Reservations</Link></li>
        <li><Link className="a" to="/">Order Online</Link></li>
        <li><Link className="a" to="/">Login</Link></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </body>
  )
}

export default Nav
```

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using? Try removing `exact` from the Route of booking. Also in `Nav` component you do not need add the `body` tag

Comment: I see no overt issues with the routing code. Are there any errors in the console?